# How to navigate the "Sheets" in a windows Form WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, excel

I converted an excel workbook into an Html file to be displayed in a web browser. As you can see in the image provided, the excel worksheets in the workbook were converted into something like a tab control labelled "End of Term", "Weekly Test" etc... in the web browser control.

How can I change the tabs or the "sheets" by code?

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHCaF.png)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.invokemember(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Could you please specify the code please. I don't understand.